# IAM events don't invoke EventBridge rule

Tags: aws-event-bridge

**What do I want**: trigger EventBridge rule when IAM user is created.

**What do I have**: EventBridge rule pattern

```json
{
  "source": ["aws.iam"]
}
```

**What's wrong**: there are zero invocations in the rule monitoring after I created an IAM user. [image]However, there is an `CreateUser` event in CloudTrail

```json
{
    "eventVersion": "1.08",
    // sensitive fields are hidden
    "eventTime": "2023-09-01T06:33:12Z",
    "eventSource": "iam.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "CreateUser",
    "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
    "readOnly": false,
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "managementEvent": true
}
```

I used different rule pattern before

```json
{
  "source": [
    "aws.iam"
  ],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "iam.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "CreateUser"
    ]
  }
}
```

but it stopped catching events after ~ 10th August. So I edited the pattern to catch all events, but it doesn't catch any.